# What is the proper way to store a complex object in Redis stream?

Tags: redis, redis-streams

Let's image that our data looks like this:

```
{
  id: 0,
  user: {
    name: "John Doe"
  },
  post: {
    id: 0,
    content: "Blah blah",
    replies: [
      {
        id: 0,
        content: "Blah blah"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the best way to store this data in a Redis Stream?

I tried of these 2 methods but they don't seem like the optimal solution

### Storing the object as JSON

For example:

```
XADD mystream * id 0 user "{"name": "John Doe"}" post "{id: 0,content: "Blah blah", replies: [{id: 0, content: "Blah blah" }]}"
```

This is easy to implement, but hurts performance.

### Storing the object in a custom format

For example:

```
XADD mystream * id 0 "user.name" "John Doe" "post.id" 0 "post.content" "Blah blah" "replies.0.id" 0 "replies.0.content" "Blah blah"
```

This would be difficult to support for multiple producers and consumers in different languages.